# use of Context menu in Expandable List View

Tags: android, contextmenu, expandablelistview

I have seen in some places that while using Expandable List View we register the list view for  context menu. I want to know that why it is done and what effect it will have on our application if we dont register our List View for context menu

Comment: are you talking about registerForContextMenu(view)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you mean by **we register the list view for context menu**?

I am sure there is a call of **`registerForContextMenu(View)`** , which describes that whenever you perform any action on that particular view, this context menu will get displayed.

In the case of Expandable ListView, if you call registerForContextMenu then it will display context menu whenever you click on any item.